# Wanting to load image and some text for the selected option in a dropdown list using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I can't find a decent example of this anywhere.

Basically have a dropdown list, each option value is the `productID` and text is the Product name.

I want to post all the selected option values to an action method that will return the respective images on document ready. Image data will the be passed to a function which will update the DOM and then execute the same function everytime a different option from dropdown list is selected to retrieve and change the selected options/product image only.

The action method will return the image for this option/value to the client in an AJAX response, I also want to return the product description too.

Should the response data-type be JSON or do I have to return it in some other way i.e HTTP response with image MIME type?

Something like the below collects all the selected values in an array:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arr = new Array();
    $('select option').each(function () {
        arr.push($(this).val());
    });

    // This below will post it off:    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/System/GetProductImages",
        data: { arr: arr },
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) { 
            mydata = data; 
            OnSuccess(data) // <--- The function that will load/update the images
        }, 
        dataType: "json" //<--- ?
    });
});
```

I am not sure how to form the AJAX request correctly so I can request both an image and some text, or is it best to make separate calls when requiring different data types? Maybe I can pack them all in into an array of some sort? Also not to sure how the function that will update the DOM with the retrieved images will look.

Comment: Hi Is the drop down list box is multiple select or single select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your response should be JSON having and `Image ID`(a value to identify your image from DB) and `Product description`. Then using that construct dynamic image elements in  HTMl and set their `src` tag to a URL by passing that `image ID` as parameter and on server side there should be a handler for your request(like servlet, which reads the Image ID and fetches image stream and returns as response). So, browser make a request for each image and get it rendered on browser. hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks.. Yes, that sounds more right than trying to somehow push binary over Json etc. Simply change the src and get browser to load new image. I already have an action method that returns the image file based on the ProductID supplied, guess I just need the script now to actually change the src so it ends with the selected productID i.e. GetImage/ProductID?=77

Comment: Exactly! that the way we can fetch the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the new data using the change event on the select box:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('select').change(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/System/GetProductImages",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 'id': $('select').selectedIndex.val() },
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) { 
                mydata = data; 
                OnSuccess(data) // <--- The function that will load/update the images
            }
        });


    });

});
```

Additionally, if you're more comfortable with PHP, you could echo out the results from the PHP script and call the load function on change of the select option like so:

```
/* JQuery code */

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('select').change(function(){

        $.load("/System/GetProductImages", function(){
         // The script to run when a successful load operation takes place
        });


    });

});

/* PHP Code */

echo "<script>$('tag name').html('value you want to set'); $('img').attr('src','new image src');</script>";
```

Though I'm not sure calling the script from within PHP is the best solution. You should also keep in mind that the Content-Type response header should be set to "application/json".

If you're using PHP, you can use the json_encode function to return a JSON result. You can read more about the PHP JSON options here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Hope this helps.